# How to get custom user model's custom fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

I've created one custom user model as below

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

Now I want to access that newly added fields(bio, location, birth_date) in my html template. How can I do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html, you can access to the users data like this: `{{user.profile.bio}}`

Firsteval, you must pass your `User` or your `Profile` object to your context.